# Adding subtitles with FFMpegCore in C# is not working on Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ffmpeg, azure-functions

I have deployed a C# azure function with ffmpeg.exe (using FFMpegCore nuget). The function adds audio and srt/ass subtitles to a video.
When I test locally this code works (running on azurite). But, when I deploy the azure function, the audio is added to the video but the subtitles don't show up.

At the begining I thought it was an issue with the Fonts because I was using ASS File for subtitles but then I switched to SRT and still is not working.

I've tried with both SRT and ASS but they both don't work using this code:

```
await FFMpegArguments
 .FromFileInput(videoInputPath, true, options =>
 {
     options.WithCustomArgument("-stream_loop -1");
 })
 .AddFileInput(audioPath, true)
 .OutputToFile(videoOutputPath, true, (options) =>
 {
     options.WithDuration(thread.AudioData.TotalAudioDuration);

     options.WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.LibX264);   // Re-encode video using x264 codec
     options.WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.Aac);       // Re-encode audio to AAC
     options.WithSpeedPreset(Speed.VeryFast);
     options.UsingShortest(true);

     options.WithVideoFilters((videoOptions) =>
     {
         videoOptions.HardBurnSubtitle(SubtitleHardBurnOptions.Create(subtitlesFile));
     });
 }).ProcessAsynchronously();
```

Here's the command it creates on Azure function:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i "C:\local\Temp\videoTempPath.mp4" -i "C:\local\Temp\audioTempPath.mp3" -t 00:00:22.8160000 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -shortest -vf "subtitles='C\:\\local\\Temp\\subtitles.srt'" "C:\local\Temp\output.mp4" -y
```

Answer (score 0):

> At the begining I thought it was an issue with the Fonts because I was using ASS File for subtitles but then I switched to SRT and still is not working.

- The way you're specifying the subtitle file path in the `HardBurnSubtitle` method it appears that the path is not correctly formatted for use within the FFmpeg command.

Specify the below format for the subtitles file path.

```cs
videoOptions.HardBurnSubtitle(SubtitleHardBurnOptions.Create(subtitlesFile.Replace("\\", "/")));
```

- Here I have a Http-trigger function which I have done with simple modifications of the above given code.

**Function1.cs:**

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FFMpegCore;

public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("AddAudioAndSubtitles")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("input/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream videoInput,
        string name,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string videoOutputPath = Path.GetTempFileName(); // Temporary file path for output video
        string audioPath = "path_to_your_audio_file.mp3"; // Replace with the path to your audio file
        string subtitlesPath = "path_to_your_subtitles_file.srt"; // Replace with the path to your subtitles file

        await FFMpegArguments
            .FromFileInput(videoInput, true)
            .AddFileInput(audioPath, true)
            .OutputToFile(videoOutputPath, true, options =>
            {
                options.WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.LibX264)
                       .WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.Aac)
                       .WithSpeedPreset(Speed.VeryFast)
                       .UsingShortest(true)
                       .WithVideoFilters(videoOptions =>
                       {
                           videoOptions.HardBurnSubtitle(SubtitleHardBurnOptions.Create(subtitlesPath.Replace("\\", "/")));
                       });
            })
            .ProcessAsynchronously();
        
        log.LogInformation($"Processed video '{name}' with audio and subtitles.");
    }
}
```

The function reads the input video file from the blob storage stream.

- The input video, audio, and subtitles files are correctly provided to the function, and the paths are properly configured in the code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am using Windows azure function so the path is '\' instead of '/'. I managed to see the ffmpeg's internal logs and it seems is an issue with fonts (fontselect: failed to find any fallback with glyph 0x0 for font: (Arial, 400, 0)).)